# Bluetooth not finding any device, now also not showing bluetooth logo at taskbar

Tags: networking, bluetooth, kde

I just installed Kubuntu 22.04 LTS, but the bluetooth is not working, I am trying from 3 days...
I don't know but after I deleted and reinstalled Bluedevil, now my bluetooth logo is also gone from taskbar...
kindly help please...

Comment: Please explain what bluedevil is. Where it came from and how you installed it.

Comment: @david , I researched about bluetooth and found out that bluedevil manages the bluetooth in kde desktop...
so I thought that by uninstalling and reinstalling it, maybe my error can get fixed...
I did it on my friend's laptop, we both have same laptop with Kubuntu 22.04 LTS running.
And it fixed his bluetooth problem, so I thought it could solve mine also... but nothing happened

Comment: bluedevil is a bluetooth transfer app. reinstalling it won't solve your problem.

Comment: How can I solve my Bluetooth problem...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; sudo dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.